# How to delete all js files excluding those which are in node_module directory?

Tags: javascript, npm

In Node.js (OS agnostic), I want to delete all js files in a npm project except those js files which are in node_module directory. How to do this?

I've tried using `del-cli` npm package with this npm script:

```
del '**/*.js' '!**/node_module/*.js'
```

but it doesn't work. It deletes js files from node_module directory and I need to perform `npm install` each time.

Comment: Get all of the directories in the current one. Iterate over them. If the name of the directory is "node_module" continue the loop. Otherwise, delete all the .js files. Do that recursively.

Answer (score 0):

try [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#readme)

firstly, install `glob`

```sh
npm install --save glob
```

then glob all `.js` files, excluding `node_modules`

```js
const glob = require("glob");

glob("!(node_modules)/**/*.js", (err, files) => {
  console.log(files);
})
```

Comment: In my setup, there are more than one `node_modules` folders.

Comment: why the above (with maybe small modification) does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

[`rimraf`](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf#readme) is pretty great for that (name is a pun on `rm -rf`). It supports [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) patterns, so something like this should work:

```
rimraf "!(node_modules)/**/*.js"
```

Comment: In my setup, there are more than one `node_modules` folders.